# select values missing from one table based upon values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using mysql and have 2 tables

table1

```
id
324
325
328
350
420
650
850
950
```

table2

```
id    mapping_id
324   1
325   2
328   3
350   4
420   5
650   1
850   2
```

I want to produce a list of all the DISTINCT field mapping_ids that are missing for the ids in table one. For example id 850 has a mapping_id of 2 so is missing 1,3,4,5 and id 950 is not even in table 2 and so is missing 1,2,3,4,5. This should give me a distinct list of 1,2,3,4,5.

I have tried various LEFT JOIN queries but cannot get the results I need. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a matrix of `id - mapping` combinations using a `cross join`.  A `not in` subquery can determine which parts of the matrix are empty:

```
select  *
from    table1 t1
cross join
        (
        select  distinct mapping_id
        from    table2
        ) mappings
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    table2 t2
        where   t2.id = t1.id
                and t2.mapping_id = mappings.mapping_id
        )
```

Comment: Thank you Andomar this is as close as I have come so far. I am sure I will get there from here. You are a legend!

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t2.mapping_id
from table1 t1, table2 t2
MINUS
select t2.id, t2.mapping_id
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thank you, but when modelled exactly this returns an empty result set.

Comment: @Termine you are right, I dind't understood your question at first, here is the correct one :)

Comment: Thank you but there is no MINUS in mysql I tried NOT EXISTS but currently to no avail. Besides as the INNER JOIN forces a match on the ids it will never return records for those that only exist in table1. My problem is that I am trying to return records (the mapping_ids) which are missing.

Comment: What's the version of MYSQL that you have? `MINUS` exists!